# Animation with timing in SnapSvg

Tags: html, svg, snap.svg

I am currently using SnapSvg and faced some problem in animation.
I have an element say circle and want it to appear with fade in animation after 10 seconds of page loading.
We can perform it like following in HTML5 SVG

```
<circle id="c1" cx="50" cy="30" r="26" fill="#ff0000" opacity="0" />
<set xlink:href="#c1" attributeName="opacity" attributeType="CSS" from="0" to="1" />
```

In SnapSVG also we can create animation without timing as follow:

```
var c1=page.circle(50,30,26);
c1.attr({
fill:"#ff0000",
opacity:0
});
c1.animate({opacity:1},1000);
```

But I am really unable to apply timing on the second case.
Somebody please help.

Comment: Just use setTimeout, like setTimeout( function() { c1.animate({ opacity: 1}, 1000) }, 10000);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done many research on that topic and came to know that @lan was absolutely right.!

The only solution to this problem is:

```
setTimeout(function(){c1.animate({opacity:"1"},1000)},1500);
```

Where the second argument in `setTimeout()` function is the time to start the animation. You can also put as many animations as you can with this with this method.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `setInterval` to add opacity steps to your SVG thus simulating fading.

---

This might give you a hint: (assuming you have an element with `id="c1"`:

```
//Function that fades out elements
function fadeOutElement(elementId,time){

    var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
    var opacity = 1;

    function fadeOut(){ 
        opacity = opacity - 0.01;
        element.setAttribute('opacity',String(opacity));
        //clear interval when opacity reaches 0;
        if (opacity<=0) clearInterval(fadeInterval);
    }
    var fadeInterval = setInterval(function(){fadeOut()},time);
}

//call function and pass arguments, id of element and the interval time for each step
fadeOutElement('c1',1);
```

Here's the **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h6mL44ww/1/)** for the above snippet

---

**Note:** 
This however *does not* use snap.svg methods which would be prefferable to use since you'd want to write uniform code throughout. So a snap.svg solution would be better.